# want difference from standard value for each value of row using Django ORM

Tags: python, django

This is my Django Model

```
class MarkSheet(models.Model):
    marks=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    ....
```

Using Django ORM I want to create extra field in queryset which contains the absolute of difference between Marks of all student and Mark given by user.
For example user given mark is

```
UserMark=76
```

and our row contains

```
Marks
67
98
65
```

then I am looking some operation in querysets which gives me some operation like ABS(Marks-UserMarks)

```
Marksheet.objects.filter(class="12").annotate(marks_diff=abs(F('Marks')-UserMarks))
```

Output should be like

```
{"mark":67,"mark_diff":9}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of SQL servers support `ABS()` function so you can use the [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method:

```
Marksheet.objects.filter(class="12") \
                 .extra({'marks_diff': 'ABS(marks-%d)' % UserMarks})
```